# Star a Gmail message with google script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, message

I'm totally new to Google Script and I'm trying to find out how to star a message that I have labeled as "R/R(short)/R(ASAP)" and has held that label for at least a day. Any suggestions? Here's what I've got so far:

```
function star2do() {
var delayDays = 1 // Enter # of days before messages are starred
var maxDate = new Date();
maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("R/R(short)/R(ASAP)");
var threads = label.getThreads();
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
  {
    threads[i].markUnread();
    threads[i].addLabel(star) //this is where I'm having issues
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
threads[i].getMessages()[0].markUnread().star();
```

Hope this helps :)